# How to retain the array value even after Filter using es6

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am filtering the multidimensional array. After the successful filter the original array value is getting changed. Please find the array and filter method i am using

```
const rDetailsList = [  
        {  
            "rDate":"April 01, 2018",
            "rList":[  
                {  
                    "aName":"GOKQG C HQFUDHFPX",
                    "aNumber":"P3799838628"
                },
                {  
                    "aName":"IGNDPJR D EKYJYC",
                    "aNumber":"P3899820579"
                }
            ]
        },
        {  
            "rDate":"Jan 01, 2018",
            "rList":[  
                {  
                    "aName":"",
                    "aNumber":"A39A4035073"
                },
                {  
                    "aName":"YVTLW K SIGLC",
                    "aNumber":"A270M040558"
                }
            ]
        }
    ];

const myFilter = (arr, num) => {
  const rDetails = arr.filter(det => !!det.rList.find(l => l.aNumber === num));
  
  return rDetails.map(det => {
    det.rList = det.rList.filter(l => l.aNumber === num);
    return det;
  });
          
};
```

When i do `console.log(myFilter(rDetailsList, 'A270M040558'))` i am getting the result as expected as below

```
 [{  
        "rDate":"Jan 01, 2018",
        "rList":[  
            {  
                "aName":"YVTLW K SIGLC",
                "aNumber":"A270M040558"
            }
        ]
    }]
```

But when i do `console.log(rDetailsList)` i am getting below result

```
const rDetailsList = [  
        {  
            "rDate":"April 01, 2018",
            "rList":[  
                {  
                    "aName":"GOKQG C HQFUDHFPX",
                    "aNumber":"P3799838628"
                },
                {  
                    "aName":"IGNDPJR D EKYJYC",
                    "aNumber":"P3899820579"
                }
            ]
        },
        {  
            "rDate":"Jan 01, 2018",
            "rList":[ 
                {  
                    "aName":"YVTLW K SIGLC",
                    "aNumber":"A270M040558"
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
```

Anyone Please help why the one of the object is removed in  `"rDate":"Jan 01, 2018".` Need solution to fix this as well.

Comment: You are mutating your object/array here: `det.rList = det.rList.filter(l => l.aNumber === num);`

Comment: yes, then without that how i can able to get the expected output of the filtered value, Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```js
return rDetails.map(det => {
  det.rList = det.rList.filter(l => l.aNumber === num);
  return det;
});
```

do

```js
return rDetails.map(det => {
  return {
    ...det,
    rList: det.rList.filter(l => l.aNumber === num)
  }
});
```